# Error with encrypt password in Laravel. "The payload is invalid."

Tags: laravel, encryption

When I create a trait to encrypt a password in a database (for security purposes) and I try to use it, I get: "The payload is invalid. How can I solve this?

```php
trait Encryptable
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable, true)) {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable, true)) {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Encryptable;

    protected $encryptable = [
        'password',
    ]; 

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are hashed, not encrypted within Laravel.  This is to protect against reversing the password back out of the database (either maliciously or from a developer).  This hash is a one-way only process, leaving no way to pull a password back out and/or send it to a user.  For security purposes, you may wish to rethink your architecture to use a hash rather than encrypting.

[Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-decrypt-hash-password-in-laravel) is a good discussion, basically saying the same thing.

Hope this helps.